# Using Directory.GetFiles in my .net website

Tags: c#, .net

When I built my .net site, I retrieved files paths using 
Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\project\images");

But when I deployed it on internet server, I have to change the link of this folder, can you help me how can I do that??  can I use relative link in Directory.GetFiles() or how??

Comment: look into `Server.MapPath()`. [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: This is usually something you would expose to a configuration file.  (web.config) Look up how to use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`.

Comment: Yes if it is a part of your project use Mike's suggestion, if it is outside use Jeremy's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the web.config have something like:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ImagesFolder" value="\Images" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

then in your ASP.NET C# code behind you can use:

```
var ImagesFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagesFolder"];

var files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(ImagesFolder));
```

mind that you need to add a reference to the `System.Configuration` assembly or you won't be able to add the using statement and access the `ConfigurationManager`.

in this way there are no hard coded values and you can write the value you want for that appsetting by editing the web.config file in the deployed folder on the web server.

Comment: your solution is very simple, but it doesn't work, can you help me more??  @ Davide Piras

Comment: there is no error, but it doesn't retrieve any path @Davide Piras

Answer (score 3):

Put the path in your *web.config*.  You shouldn't be hard coding paths anyway.  What if it changes in the future?

In your settings add:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="myPath" value="D:\project\images"/>
</appSettings>
```

...and then call it from your application:

```
var myPath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myPath"];
```

If you really want to go nuts, look into [web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) so that when you publish, your release configuration will be transformed and applied for you!

Comment: it doesn't retrieve any path, mypath still empty sting, why?

Comment: @Alaa There's not much more to it.  Are you sure that you are using the right key name?

Comment: If your key name is incorrect, it's not going to throw an error -- just return null.

Comment: There is obviously something you're missing -- I even performed a sanity check to ensure this worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is by using [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
Which maps the virtual path in your web app to the physical path in the server.